# K-means convergence to local maxima

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning, clustering

I study [K-means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) clustering algorithm.

It's known that K-means algorithm converges to the local maximum, the problem is I cannot come up with the examples that shows this.

If you know the simple example, when K means doesn't calculate the optimal solution, please share it with us.

Comment: See the example near the end of the paper: http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~roweis/csc2515-2006/readings/lloyd57.pdf

Comment: @user2943324, I am sorry I cannot find the usage of k-means there.

Comment: The algorithm there is a precursor to k-means. But the analysis in appendix A is still valid. (or so I think). See if this helps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_algorithm. I only mention that reference because the counter example is remarkably simple.

Comment: Please state your question more precisely. A local maximum of which objective function?

Comment: @HansEngler But that is the question! An objective function for which the local optima determined by k-means is different from global optima.